# Mongoengine aggregate not working

Tags: mongoengine

I have the following code in mongonengine:

```
Lend.objects.filter().aggregate(
    {"$group": {"_id": "$dni"}}
)
```

But it doesn't work. I'm getting the followint output:

http://pastebin.com/E82cVqXP

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply the `aggregate` after the filter. Try:

```
Lend.objects.aggregate(
    {"$group": {"_id": "$dni"}}
)
```